# How to use set_exclusive_mouse on python arcade?

Tags: python, game-development, arcade

Can anyone provide an example of this method on the arcade library? I looked at the explanation on the site but I don't understand it. I'm looking forward to it having a feature that can make the object move on mouse motion without the cursor position. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Probably you don't need to use `set_exclusive_mouse`. Instead, hide mouse cursor with `set_mouse_visible` and capture cursor position with `on_mouse_motion`:

```
import arcade

class MyGame(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(600, 400)
        self.set_mouse_visible(False)
        self.mouse_x = None
        self.mouse_y = None

def on_draw(self):
    arcade.start_render()
    if self.mouse_x and self.mouse_y:
        arcade.draw_text(f'Cursor position: {self.mouse_x} {self.mouse_y}', 0, 370, arcade.color.RED, font_size=25)
        arcade.draw_circle_filled(self.mouse_x, self.mouse_y, 18, arcade.color.RED)

def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
    self.mouse_x = x
    self.mouse_y = y

MyGame()
arcade.run()
```

Example:

[image]